# Relation between bound of a function and it's derivatives in a compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

Is there any relation between bounds of a function and it's derivatives in a compact set or a closed and bounded interval under some conditions?

i.e. if  $ \mid f(x)\mid \leq M $ then is it possible that for some values of $n$, $\mid f^n(x)\mid \leq g(M) $ for some function $g$ or vice versa under some conditons on $x$ and $f(x)$ where $x$ belongs to a compact set.

Comment: Think of $f_n(x) = \sin( n x)$ ...

Comment: Dear Martin R., thanks for your reply. here I'm asking about general case not a particular function. there may be some conditions on $ f(x)$. I particularly interested about  n=1,2,3

Comment: The examples shows that there is no bound of the derivatives in terms of the bound of the function.

Comment: Again: $f_n(x) = \sin( n x)$ on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Okay Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Another way to think about this is that derivatives do not have to be bounded.  On $[0,1]$ the function $f(x)=x^2 \sin \frac{1}x$ is certainly bounded but the derivative is not, quite dramatically so.  Derivatives do have to have many points of continuity so there is local boundedness at those points.